Printer Scanner Epson NX420 stopped working after upgrade to ubuntu 24.04.1, unable to install drivers from Epson website
A few weeks ago my system upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 and many things that used to work no longer do.
My printer/scanner Epson NX420 wouldn´t print or scan anymore. I downloaded the drivers from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX and opening epson-printer-utility_1.1.3-1_amd64.deb I get:
Error:Cannot satisfy dependencies
I tried the printer manager but on all the Epson options NX420 is not listed and I have no idea which one in the list might be compatible. Also not sure if that would get the scanner to work.
How do I get the printer and scanner to work again?
